# How to calculate time worked in Google Sheets after 12am?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-cell-format

I usually work from 3pm to 1am. I can't seem to find out how to make google sheets find the correct duration between those times. I know the correct duration is 10 hours, but no matter what I do google sheets comes up with either 16hours and 14 hours.

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Answer (score 1):

- try to format it as **Automatic**, **Time** or **Custom Time** instead of **Duration**

[image]

- or you can format it as **Duration** if you add date **31/12/1899** before your time

[image]

Comment: Thanks @user0  I had my A and B cells formatted as time, and the C cell as duration. I thought it would have worked, but it would always count from 1am to 3pm, instead of 3pm to 1am. It didnt even occur to me to try to use Automatic. Thanks again!